# How to position a matplotlib patch outside of the axes range (so that it could be next to the title, or legend, or anywhere on the figure)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given the following code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 22, 11, 4, 6], s=100)
_ = ax.text(x=0, y=1.1, s="This is some text", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=20)

rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle(
    (0.5, 0.5), width=0.05, height=0.05, color="red", transform=ax.transAxes,
)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

Which creates:

[image]

I would like to add the patch to the following location:

[image]

So that the plot looks as follows:

[image]

It seems that I am unable to have patches outside of the axes spines area though, for example the following code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 22, 11, 4, 6], s=100)
_ = ax.text(x=0, y=1.1, s="This is some text", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=20)

rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle(
    (0.5, 0.5), width=0.05, height=0.5, color="red", transform=ax.transAxes,
)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

gives

[image]

Looking in the method for `matplotlib.figure.Figure` I can't see anything for `add_patch`

```
['_clippath',
 '_path_effects',
 'get_clip_path',
 'get_path_effects',
 'get_transformed_clip_path_and_affine',
 'patch',
 'patches',
 'set_clip_path',
 'set_path_effects']
```

The above are the methods with `pat` in them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable clipping by setting `clip_on=False`, and then you can position the patch where you want.  For example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 22, 11, 4, 6], s=100)
_ = ax.text(x=0, y=1.1, s="This is some text", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=20)

rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle(
    (0.5, 1.1), width=0.05, height=0.05, color="red", transform=ax.transAxes,
    clip_on=False
)

ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chr(9607)` to represent the patch:

```
print("This is some text", chr(9607)*3)
```

Output:

```
This is some text ▇▇▇
```

---

Into your code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 22, 11, 4, 6], s=100)
_ = ax.text(x=0, y=1.1, s=f"This is some text {chr(9607)*3}", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=20)

rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle(
    (0.5, 0.5), width=0.05, height=0.05, color="red", transform=ax.transAxes,
)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

Comment: sorry - but I don't think this would be very general, what If I wanted it twice the size? Or a circle, or multiple rectangles above and below the text? For an answer It needs to be a patch object

Comment: @baxx You *can* put the text inside the coordinates.

Comment: Yes I can write ax.text within the coordinates, and it's known that a patch can be written within there, but that would not be straightforward with what I need to do outside of this, whereas if I was able to add a patch object outside of the axes area my task would be straightforward.

Comment: if you're interested there was a parameter called `clip_on` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747618/3130747