# How can I add rectangles and labels above an audio timeseries plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

I am working with audio timeseries and want to better label areas that are being plotted.  I believe this question is general to labelling timeseries data in `matplotlib`, but it may be important that I am also using `librosa.display.waveplot` to initially plot the waveform. Currently, I am able to make the following plot using `librosa` and `matplotlib` (in a jupyter notebook):

[image]

I would like to make something like the following:
[image]

The code I used is as follows, where `x[1]` is a simple vector containing the audio data (happens to be stereo), and `target_len` is the length of a recording that is repeated 3 times with some filtering.  The audio file was imported using `x, Fs = librosa.load("audiofile.wav", mono=False)`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
librosa.display.waveplot(x[1], sr=Fs, color='black')
plt.xlabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.axvspan(0, target_len, color = 'magenta', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
plt.axvspan(target_len, target_len*2, color = 'yellow', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
plt.axvspan(target_len*2, target_len*3,color = 'blue', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
plt.tight_layout()
```

My attempts at drawing rectangles directly above the audio waveform have failed, and the best I could do is create another figure above the audio figure produced by librosa, drawing a rectangle using a patch.  Unfortunately the rectangle is being placed way too far away from where I want it.

[image]

The code for this rectangle is here (with `ax.axis('off')` commented out so you can see the poor placement of the figure):

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.04, 0), 0.35, 0.05, facecolor="black"))
#ax.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout
```

Again, this question is fundamentally about `matplotlib` and figure annotation, and specifically about how to annotate the plots that `librosa` (or any other consumer of matplotlib for that matter) makes.  It seems like `librosa` applies some of it's own formatting to the figure so it does not align well with what I try to draw in a new figure above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very experienced in customizing matplotlib. I created the code by referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747295/how-to-position-a-matplotlib-patch-outside-of-the-axes-range-so-that-it-could-b). I think there is a better way to adjust the position as it is set manually.

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib as mpl

file_name = '/content/test.wav'
wav, sr = librosa.load(file_name, sr=44100)

target_len = 1.5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
librosa.display.waveplot(wav, sr, color='black')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax.axvspan(0, target_len, color = 'magenta', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
ax.axvspan(target_len, target_len*2, color = 'yellow', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
ax.axvspan(target_len*2, target_len*3,color = 'blue', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)
# t = fig.transFigure
# print(t)
a = ax.transAxes
print(a)
plt.text(0.25, 1.0, 'Audio 1', ha='center', va='top', transform=fig.transFigure)
plt.text(0.45, 1.0, 'Audio 2', ha='center', va='top', transform=fig.transFigure)
plt.text(0.70, 1.0, 'Audio 3', ha='center', va='top', transform=fig.transFigure)
rect1 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((0.0, 1.02), width=0.295, height=0.05, color="black", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
rect2 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((0.30, 1.02), width=0.295, height=0.05, color="black", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
rect3 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((0.60, 1.02), width=0.295, height=0.05, color="black", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.add_patch(rect2)
ax.add_patch(rect3)
# plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

BboxTransformTo(
    TransformedBbox(
        Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.125, x1=0.9, y1=0.88),
        BboxTransformTo(
            TransformedBbox(
                Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=12.0, y1=3.0),
                Affine2D(
                    [[72.  0.  0.]
                     [ 0. 72.  0.]
                     [ 0.  0.  1.]])))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) takes two optional arguments `ymin` and `ymax`, in units relative to the height of the Y axis. 1.0 is top of Y axis, 0.0 is bottom of Y axis.
So try using `ymin=1.1` and `ymax=1.2` or something similar.